# Checked box should stay checked PHP

Tags: php, html

if i check the checkbox, the checkbox should stay checked. I got a form where it gets checked after submit, but it should staying checked without any Submit. is it possible with php?

Code:

```
$checkbox=false;
if (isset($_POST['psp-ele'])){
    $checkbox=true;                         
};
?>
<input type="checkbox" name="psp-ele" id="Investnr" class="Investnr" <?php if ($checkbox==true) { echo "checked='checked'";}; ?> >
```

Comment: Your question is not clear

Comment: Do you get `checked='checked'` in the source? Is `var_dump($_POST['psp-ele'])` set?

Comment: php is a server side language. So it is executed **only on page load**. Once the page is loaded you hve to use javascript to modify the DOM since javascript is a client side language

Comment: @IndraKumarS The Checkbox just have to be stayed checked

Comment: What is your quetion? You want the checkbox to be checked 'before submit'. So that means you want it to be checked by default, that is the form should be checked when it loads. Is that what you want?

Comment: Are you submitting the form to the page ? And you want the form to have checked input as checked again ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the checkbox to stay checked when you load the page without a form submit then you should keep that information in the session and set the value from the session when parsing the checkbox:

In your form processor:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['psp-ele'] = isset($_POST['psp-ele']);
```

Where ever you want to parse it:

```
<?php
// start the session if it has not already been started
if (session_status() === PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
    session_start();
}
?>
<input type="checkbox" name="psp-ele" id="Investnr" class="Investnr" <?php if ($_SESSION['psp-ele']) { echo 'checked'; }; ?> >
```

Answer (score 0):

The initial load of your page that contains the form is likely to happen via a GET request - so simply add a check if the request method was GET, and also set your flag to true in that case:

```
$checkbox=false;
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET' || isset($_POST['psp-ele'])){
    $checkbox=true;                         
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the form to be checked by default and after submit want to persist the users selection then you can simply add another condition which checks if the variable has been defined or not with `isset`.

```php
if(!empty($_POST)){
    if (isset($_POST['psp-ele'])){
       $checkbox = true;                         
    }else{
       $checkbox = false;
    }
}
<input type="checkbox" name="psp-ele" id="Investnr" class="Investnr" <?php if (!isset($checkbox) || $checkbox) { echo "checked='checked'";}; ?> >
```

The `isset` checks the checkbox when loading for the first time and the `$checkbox` variable does it after being submitted.

Comment: OP explicitly sets the variable both outside and inside the `if` condition, so `!isset` will never evaluate to `true`.

Comment: @El_Vanja I assumed the php block would be executed after the form is submitted. Made an edit to make it work even if the block is executed on formload.

Comment: It's still not good after the edit. An empty array is considered set. `$_POST` is an always defined superglobal, it always exists. It's only the content that depends on the type of request.

Comment: @El_Vanja Yes you are right. Corrected the post again. I have personally used `isset` sparsely and hence the mistake. Thanks for correcting.